# How to customize built in WPF control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to customize the built-in Calendar in WPF. I've already created multiple custom ControlTemplates for all parts of the calendar, but I want to further change the fundamentals of how the calendar works.

It seems that this can only be achieved by modifying the C# class code of the control. As I've read, editing an internal .NET class is not a good idea. So, I thought of copying the code to my own CustomCalendar class (code from [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Calendar.cs,aea468169f94a1ef)). However, it uses some internal namespaces (MS.Internal.Telemetry.PresentationFramework) which Visual Studio can't find because, well, it's internal.

Is there a way to still use these internal namespaces, or is there a simpler way to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: "I want to further change the fundamentals of how the calendar works." - use inheritance: `public class CustomCalendar : Calendar { overrides and custom methods }`

Comment: What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you can't modify it through inheritance.

Comment: You will likely need to either make your own from scratch or find a third party control that is more to your liking. The .Net framework is not open source, so you cannot copy any code without making copyright infringement. Inheritance seem to provide very little in the way of customization, since the vast majority of methods are non virtual and private/internal.

Comment: @JonasH The source they linked is 99.9% identical to the [MIT-licensed source](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/Calendar.cs) from .NET core, it would be difficult to argue copyright infringement.

Comment: @JonasH are you being sarcastic? You should know full well modern .NET is open source and that the OP is likely only linking to the obsolete Framework source they found online. If they want to harvest the source for Calendar.cs from the Github WPF repo and customize it they have every right to.

Comment: @suljic this is the source file to the modern .NET WPF code that is open source. https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/53bf3e3c0fa248deee2587397a9162eb59ab5f1b/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/Calendar.cs#L4.  Whoever told you this isn't "a good idea" unlikely understood what you were trying to do. If you want to make a totally custom Calendar control that's derivative of the "official" version you can. Good luck.

Comment: @EmperorEto I don't know if the OP linked the wrong source file by mistake, or if he needs to use .net framework. Or for that matter, if there are any significant differences between the .Net framework versions and the Open Source .Net core versions. But including a file in your repo with a "Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved" will at the very least look quite bad.